# Как запустить Activity поверх всех остальных окон

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как то запустить `Activity` поверх экрана стандартной звонилки?
Читал что так можно сделать, но не могу нагуглить как это делаеться.

Comment: Уточните вопрос: запускаемое активити должно полностью перекрыть активити звонилки? Нельзя ли просто с помощью intent() на него переключится?

Comment: да, я хочу полностью перекрыть экран звонилки!